# WPF two-way binding

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a `textbox` with the property FontSize = "12" and a `slider`, and what I do not remember is how to use the command = mode twoway and when moving the `slider` resize the text of the `textbox`.

Here I leave the code that I am trying to use but it does not work for me

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Margin="16,16,16,49" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="12" />

<Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,78,0,-1"
            Width="166" Maximum="50" Minimum="12" Value="{Binding
            Path=Textbox1.fontsize,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, i.e. bind the `Value` of the `Slider` to the `FontSize` property of the `TextBox` using `ElementName`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Margin="16,16,16,49" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="12" />

<Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,78,0,-1"
            Width="166" Maximum="50" Minimum="12" Value="{Binding Path=FontSize, ElementName=TextBox1}" />
```